# Google Speech Recognition Streaming API via curl

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to use Googles Speech Recognition API via the streaming method, so I stream my file and get the text in real time back. That is needed so I know when something was said in the audio file. The problem is, that I don't use any of the languages Google provides an SDK for and their documentation doesn't show how to make such a request without their SDKs.

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Streaming support for Google Cloud Speech Recognition API is available [**only through gRPC**](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize), the reason being it is tough or almost impossible to implement streaming with just plain old REST APIs.

> Streaming Speech Recognition allows you to stream audio to the Cloud
>   Speech API and receive a stream speech recognition results in real
>   time as the audio is processed. See also the audio limits for
>   streaming speech recognition requests. Streaming speech recognition is
>   available via gRPC only.

Having said that the [Cloud Speech API Client library is available in the following languages](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) and covers a decent spectrum of common developer languages.

> - C#
> - Go
> - Java
> - Node.JS
> - PHP
> - Python
> - Ruby

Since you haven't mentioned the language you're using, and if you do use a language other than one from the above list, you could very well look into the client library source code (for a different language) and how it uses gRPC to do the streaming and implement it in the language you're using.

Again the only limitation now is a [language which gRPC has support for](http://www.grpc.io/docs/). Compared to the above list, gRPC has support for C++ and Objective C. So if you are using one of them, this could very well be a viable option albeit with a lot of digging into the client library codebase.

I do agree that having support for C++ and/or ObjectiveC in the google client libraries will be really useful for developers.

**UPDATE**:
On a quick search, I found [**this github repo**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api) which has few samples on how to call the Google Cloud Speech API using C++ (still not sure if that is the language you're using though).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I use Elixir which is not provided with a gRPC implementation. Seems like I have to build a small script in one of the supported languages then.

Comment: @Phillipp - Yes you will have to invoke a call into a program running in any of these supported languages. I'm not too familiar with elixir, but I think using a RPC library which has elixir support as well as support for any of the above languages will also solve your problem. `Elixir program <--RPC--> Python <--Speech API Client lib--> Google Speech API Service` (taking Python as an example and assuming the RPC library has Python and elixir support).